# Animate between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 divs, 1 is just off the screen to the left, and the other visible. the divs contain unordered lists. Now when i click on one of the 'li' list items i would like to slide div 1 to the left off screen and bring div 2 to the right on screen. so this is what i have done so far:

```
<script>
var swap =0;
$("(#cat)li:first").click(function(){
    if(swap==0){
        $("#cat").animate({"left": "-=150px"}, "slow");
        $("#cat2").animate({"left": "+=130px"}, "slow");
        swap=1;
    }
    else{
        $("#cat").animate({"left": "+=150px"}, "slow");
        $("#cat2").animate({"left": "-=130px"}, "slow");
        swap=0;
    }
});
</script>
```

cat and cat2 are the 2 divs with cat2 initially offscreen to the left. Now it sort of works but not quite. Right now i can click anywhere on screen and the 2 switch. But how do i do it so when i click on a list item it does the swap?

Note: I want to later be able to grab the text in list item to use, and it maybe be any of the list items not just the first.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To start it looks like your jquery selector isn't formatted correctly. If you want it to fire on only the first list item click then change

```
$("(#cat)li:first")
```

to

```
$("#cat li:first, #cat2 li:first")
```

This says, for the first list item in div #cat or #cat2 do this. Your question is phrased as though you want it for all list items though, in which case you would want.

```
$("#cat li, #cat2 li") or $("li")
```

**Example Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var swap =0;
        $("#cat li, #cat2 li").click(function(){
                if(swap==0){
                        $("#cat").animate({"left": "-=150px"}, "slow");
                        $("#cat2").animate({"left": "+=130px"}, "slow");
                        swap=1;
                }
                else{
                        $("#cat").animate({"left": "+=150px"}, "slow");
                        $("#cat2").animate({"left": "-=130px"}, "slow");
                        swap=0;
                }
        });
    });

    </script>
    <style>
        li { border: 1px solid red; }
        #cat { position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 150px; }
        #cat2 { position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="cat">
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="cat2">
        <ul>
            <li>w</li>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>y</li>
            <li>z</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes because i want to grab the test from the list item. So i tried to do $("#cat li, #cat2 li") but it only works once, and when i click again nothing happens?

Comment: Sounds like you are introducing a javascript error which probably breaks your script. I will update my original post with my full code which swaps the lists back and forth.

Comment: Ah thanks, i left out the $(document).ready(function () { ... });    Just for my knowledge, why does leaving that out make a different?

Comment: document.ready tells jquery to wait until all elements of the DOM have been loaded. This is different than the onload event you may have seen in javascript. They have a good explanation on their website. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: install Firebug for Firefox or press Ctrl-shift-J in Chrome, then you see errors when the Javascript is not running and it tells you why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/